Why does Flatpak install applications in /var instead of /usr?
I've noticed that Flatpak, a popular package manager for Linux, installs applications in the /var directory instead of the traditional /usr directory.
While /usr has been the conventional location for installing applications, Flatpak opts for /var, a directory used for variable data such as logs, spools, and temporary files.
What are the reasons behind this decision? Does it offer any advantages over the traditional approach?

Reason? it's all conventions, so the reason is "we stick to conventions so to confuse the least people and tools possible". But why these conventions exists has no reason, other than at some point people saying "ok, that's how we usually do it". In some cases (LHS, see below), convention got explicitly written down and motivated; but that doesn't change its "unreasonable" genesis.
The whole idea of Flatpak is that the installed software is not interfering with other software, so installing it where everything else is installed (and the same software in different versions) is 100% contrary to why it exists. And a subdirectory like /usr/flatpak would also run afoul of other conventions, especially that user installations are not allowed to change /usr. In fact, image-based Linux distributions, which are especially interested in flatpak, will flat out not allow installation of anything into directories below /usr.
So, that's why "not /usr". Why /var? It's not /var/, it's specifically /var/lib/flatpak.
The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard gives /var/lib exactly the role that flatpak needs it to have: Mutable state that survives reboots. That's also where container tools like mock put their containers!

I understand what you're trying to say. However, I'm still concerned about the inconsistency between the name of the directory /var and some of its contents. Flatpak applications can't be considered particularly variable compared to applications installed by traditional package managers. It feels like initially the /var directory was intended only for temporary files, but with the emergence of image-based distributions, its purpose had to change. This doesn't seem quite right to me.

But they are absolutely variable data from the view of the Linux distro. They are definitely correctly put under /var/lib, if one follows LHS. And I will be honest: what anyone thinks today that /var was originally for has absolutely no relevance here.

If you think about it, all data in the system are essentially variable, unless we're talking about image-based distributions. However, the original meaning of the directory is still important because it determines the directory's name and many files traditionally stored within it. Changing the meaning of directories leads to inconsistency within the operating system's directory structure.

you really don't have a point there. This is all convention, and the LHS is a broadly accepted, explicitly written down convention. So, your points could be valid, but you're still missing the point. Nobody cares what you think is right! This is how "we" as community, by and large, have agreed to organize our distros. It's nice that you have your own ideas, but in the end, it's just being "special for the sake of being special", if you adhered to these deviating ideas.

Unfortunately, it seems that our conversation isn't leading to a constructive and respectful dialogue. Therefore, I'd prefer to end it here.

I'd agree, we're not moving forward. You want to argue the standard – something that I cannot offer, I'm afraid.
